# How do I have two buttons go to the same IBOutlet in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is there a simple way in doing this? Like dragging the button to the target?

Answer (score 0):

An IBOutlet is just a way to automate instantiating a variable with an object. A pointer to a UIButton cannot simultaneously reference two objects. So, no you cannot hook up two buttons to the same IBOutlet.

Since you mention "target" in your question, perhaps what you want to know is how to have two buttons invoke the same method (*IBAction*). There are a couple of ways to do this. In the simplest case:

1. right-click on the button,
2. drag from the appropriate sent event (probably touch-up-inside) to the file owner
3. as you hover over the file owner, you'll see a pop-up with all the methods marked as IBActions; select the method you wish to invoke.

Comment: But for some reason, this can't be done for two buttons. When I right-click and drag, it's like only one or the other can be represented. (Correction)

Comment: If you can provide more detail about what you are trying to do and what is not working, then perhaps somebody can spot what you are doing incorrectly. I have been able to "wire up" two buttons so the same action in multiple projects with no difficulty.